# How do I find matching subGridOptions.data element for expanded row?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In Angular UI-Grid v4.0.4, I have a button called "ViewLog" for each row that's inside an expandable row. I'm trying to display the data that's inside the child row when the ViewLog button is clicked.

**This is the structure**

```
Parent Row 1
  |
  --- (ViewLog) Child 1 (json for child 1)
  --- (ViewLog) Child 2 (json for child 2)
  --- (ViewLog) Child 3 ...
  |
Parent Row 2
  |
  --- (ViewLog) Child 1 (json for child 1)
  --- (ViewLog) Child 2 ...
```

**The code for `expandable`:**

```
gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, function (row) {
    if (row.isExpanded) {
        row.entity.subGridOptions = {
            appScopeProvider: $scope,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    name: 'Log',
                    field: '',
                    width: "85",
                    cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="grid.appScope.displayLogFile(row.entity.subGridOptions.data[howToFindRightElement]);">View Log</button>'
                }
            ]
        };
    }
});
```

In my example above, in `cellTemplate`, `row.entity.subGridOptions.data` is an array. I can't seem to figure out how to identify the correct element from that array that matches the child row selected after expanding the Parent row.

I just want to find the JSON from the child row and pass it over to `displayLogFile()`.

Comment: Could you possible give more code?  In the sense of how the row.entity is supposed to be structured.

Comment: @JonBlack There's nothing else to show, I'm simply trying to find out what the current subGrid row is, the row where the button was pressed so that I can fetch the element from the row.entity.subGridOptions.data[].

Comment: So thats my confusion. Its hard to understand what you are setting up with this.  I'm not understanding where `appLogB64` is coming from.  Is it supposed to come from the original row that you expanded? Or is it coming from additional data that you are getting with the subGridOptions?

Comment: @JonBlack Sorry I should've cleared that off from the code sample, it's irrelevant. I just don't know how to find the right element from that array, the element that properly matches the row I'm currently on after expanding the parent row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to see the data of a newly generated ui grid that is created after expanding the row. If that is the case, then I think you need to treat is as another scope. The `row.entity in expandable !== row.entity in cellTemplate`.  That being the case, then all you should need is this `row.entity`.  So the following columnDef setup should work.

```
row.entity.subGridOptions = {
    appScopeProvider: $scope,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    name: 'Log',
                    field: '',
                    width: "85",
                    cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="grid.appScope.displayLogFile(row.entity);">View Log</button>'
                }
            ]
        };
```

Comment: Jon, `howToFindRightElement` is just a placeholder I put there since that is the part I can't hard code. I won't know what data to load from the array since I'm not sure what row the user clicked on. That's what I'm trying to figure out. Identify the row the user clicked on *the child rows, not parent* then I will know what data to fetch from the array.

Comment: ohhhh okay, I see now.